# Android app reopening and proceeding on the next activity even when pressing the home button or back button

Tags: java, android, android-homebutton

I wrote this app that in the first screen it has an included Thread on it. So it has I timed it like 7 seconds then it will proceed to the next activity.

The problem is whenever I hit the home button the music will stop and it will go to android homescreen but after my timed is done which is the 7 seconds, the app will reappear and will show the next activity.

I tried putting `finish();` in the `onpause();` but it's still showing the next activity.

here's the actual code.

```
public class HelloWorldActivity extends Activity {
    MediaPlayer mp;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.otj);
        mp.start();

        Thread LogoTimer = new Thread(){
            public void run(){
                try{
                    int LogoTimer = 0;
                while(LogoTimer < 7000){
                    sleep(100);
                    LogoTimer = LogoTimer + 100;


                    }


                startActivity(new Intent("com.example.HelloWorld.CLEARSCREEN"));
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                    finally{
                    finish();
                    }

            }
        };
        LogoTimer.start();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDestroy();
        mp.release();



    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();
        mp.pause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onStop();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First, that's a really inefficient way to run a timer.  Try this way instead:

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

    public void run() {
        // Do some work.
    }

}, delayTimeInMs);
```

Second, your starting a new activity when that timer eventually fires.  It doesn't matter that the originating activity is finished.  Your startActivity() is running on it's own thread and will execute regardless.

It's possible the postDelayed() method will function like you expect.  If not you'll need to have it check when it runs whether it should really start the activity.  However, I think the Handler is attached to the default Looper which means it will stop (or rather, the message won't be posted) if the main activity finishes.

Comment: I was following a tutorial so this is what i followed. I'm going to leave the methods? Like the onpause(); onstop(); onDestroy(); etc. Sorry if i have to ask this I'm really just a beginner on android.

Comment: Yes, those methods look fine.  I haven't done any media player work so I don't know the recommended way to get it and release it.  I would be tempted to put the MediaPlayer.create() in onStart() and release it in onStop() instead of onDestroy().

Comment: Ok i got it working and it's not returning to the application again when i try to hit the home button. Thank you. Now I might need a good Java book for Android because the tutorials on youtube aren't really that good.

Answer (score 2):

The application is still in the background and the thread is not destroyed so it will fire the startActivity.

I would not really setup a splash screen this way, or use a thread unless I wanted it off the UI for some reason, even then there are better options.

For educational purposes to take care of this you need to be able to abort the thread safely in onPause() one way to do so is below

Modifed Thread

```
    Thread LogoTimer = new Thread() {

    private volatile boolean abortThread = false;

       public void run(){

       long stopAt = System.currentTimeMillis() + 7000;

       while (!abortThread && stopAt > System.currentTimeMillis())
          yield();

       if (!abortThread)
           startActivity ... 
     }

    public synchronized void stopThread() {
        abortThread = true;
    }
};
```

Comment: where should i put the startActivity now?

Comment: Oh same place, this was just a skeleton to show you how to stop the thread, but here I will modify for you, stand by

Comment: @regi - see above, but also note the first solution by Walt that uses a runnable is probably better for your purposes because you are not doing any real work, I was just showing you how to solve the issue if you did have a thread

Comment: ok, last thing. What is the bad thing about my original code? That was a tutorial from youtube so that's how i did it.

Comment: @regi Your use of it is fairly benign in that probably won't cause any issues it's just overkill and not the typcial Android way of handling this, threads typically take up more resources/cpu that's all.